# Python: random() takes no arguments

Tags: python

I am attempting to create nxn matrices which contain random variables between 0 and 1. I am created the following code (default of matrice size is 10x10):

```
class MatrixParameters:
     def __init__(self, matrix_size=10):
             self.matrix_size= matrix_size


def RMatrix(param):
       assert isinstance(param, MatrixParameters)
       rnd_1 = random.random(param.matrix_size)
       rnd_2 = random.random(param.matrix_size)
       return rnd_1,rnd_2
```

I am getting the error: random() takes no arguments (1 given). I have read the forum and I am not sure .choice is the way forward. How have I screwed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) method does not take arguments.

If you would like to generate range of numbers between 0 to 1. Then you could do,

```
[random.random() for i in range(10)] # To generate 10 random numbers, replace 10 with params.matrix_size.
```

Or with numpy.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.random(10)
```

Comment: great thanks! much appreciated, I cant up vote yet...bt this answerers my question.

Answer (score 2):

Error is kind of explicit, but you can also check [the random.random() doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.random).

As you can see, `random.random()` does not expect any argument, but you given one (`param.matrix_size`).

If you wants a random integer between two integers, uses [random.randint()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) like `random.randint(0, params.matrix_size)`